# JavaScript Regular Expression in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

Im trying to remove all nondigit character from string in javascript.
In FF and Chrome it works fine, but in IE11 it not working and nothing is removed.

```
var prunedText  = pastedText.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,"");
```

Comment: "It's not working" does us nothing. Give a concrete example of the input it doesn't handle, the output you expect, and the output you get instead.

Comment: I want to insert into input string="325eclipboardData59879879" and with a function remove all letters to: "3255987987".
In FF and Chrome it is OK but in IE it paste whole string with letters.

Comment: [Works just fine in IE11](http://output.jsbin.com/ralijoreva). It would be truly shocking if it didn't.

Comment: yeah problem solved -> thanks

Comment: Um...there's no problem to solve above. The posted code works. Although Ankit's code *also* works, that's largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/\D/g` as it works in IE also:

```js
var myString = 'adasd125dasd45asd45';
myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,'');
console.log(myString);
```